# open javafx window with it's relative path

Tags: javafx, path

I need to open a fxml window from a javafx controler

```
Stage graphStage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    fenetre = new File("../graph/graph.fxml");
    if (!fenetre.exists()) {
        System.out.println("fichier inexistant");
    } else {
        Pane rootGraph = loader.load(getClass().getResource(fenetre.getPath()).openStream());
        GraphController controller = (GraphController) loader.getController();
        controller.getSystemChoice(id);
        Scene sceneGraph = new Scene(rootGraph);
        sceneGraph.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("myStyle.css").toExternalForm());

        graphStage.setTitle("Graphe");
        graphStage.setScene(sceneGraph);
        graphStage.show();
    }
```

the code doesn't fincd the file, how to reach this file ?

```
controler is on: cloud/composant/controler.java
my fxml is on:   cloud/graph/graph.fxml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you get the data from a file or you use a resource.

Do not try to combine both approaches. They are often incompatible.

```
// assuming here the file path is correct
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fenetre.toURI().toURL());
...
Pane rootGraph = loader.load();
```

If the file is a resource, you should prefer to load it as resource though:

```
// assuming cloud is positioned in the "classpath root"
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/cloud/graph/graph.fxml"));
```

Comment: same error persists, I've mentioned the paths on the post, is the notation correct ?

Comment: @devhicham A relative path means it's relative... Relative to the working directory, which you haven't mentioned. Resources should better be stored as resources though in which case the second approach should work assuming `cloud` is directly stored in the "package root" and you run the rpogram in a way that includes the resources in the classpath...

Comment: thank you ^_^, I've added the test file so I can find the cause of the error